# Carbon difference two dates in weeks

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, php-carbon

I have a date in this format: '2017-09-26 00:02:37'. I am trying to calculate the difference of this date and now, and get the value in months.
Eg. (52 weeks)

What is the proper way of achieving this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a function in Carbon called `diffInWeeks()`

```
$date->diffInWeeks($otherDate);
```